What is the product and quotient between algebraic structures called?
I am looking for some concept in universal/abstract algebra that is analogous to quotient groups.
Imagine some operations on algebraic structures (*) and its inverse (/)
I am struggling to define them precisely but the idea would be that some structures entail others such as:
Lattice = Join-semilattice * Meet-semilattice.
Lattice/Join-semilattice = Meet-semilattice
Vector Space = Field * Abelian Group
Vector Space/Field = Abelian Group
Unital Magma * Semigroup = Monoid
Monoid / Unital Magma = Semigroup
Is there a formal name for such a relationship?

I'm not sure it's what you're asking, but if $\mathbf A=(A,F)$ is an algebra, where $F$ is a set of operations on $A$, then, for $F'\subset F$, to $\mathbf A'=(A,F')$ we call an algebraic reduct of $\mathbf A$; if $F''\supset F$, then, sometimes, to $\mathbf A''=(A,F'')$ we call an expansion of $\mathbf A$.

Vector Space seems out of place compared to the other. A monoid is both a unital magma and a semigroup, but a vector space isn't a field. Also, Vector Space generally isn't considered a kind of structure, $F$-Vector Space for a particular field $F$ is.

@duck Vector spaces form a two-sorted theory, one for the field, one for the additive group. You don't necessarily need to fix the field. This is relevant for example when defining semi-linear maps, and therefore appears in Galois cohomology. In any case, every vector space has an underlying / associated field. In the same way that every monoid has an underlying semigroup etc.

@MartinBrandenburg I agree with your comment, but one should add that vector spaces over a fixed field as duck refers are usually considered. It has the advantage that no heterogeneous algebra has to be dealt with, at the cost of what might be seen as a disadvantage in some contexts, which is that they have a unary operation for each member of the field (the same for modules over rings); that's the usual thing in Universal Algebra, I think.

Also, I must bring this other subject here, although it was perhaps only a matter of sloppy presentation of the ideas: lattices are not just algebras with two semilattice operations; the absorption laws play an important role relating those two, and without them, the result would be a bi-semilattice, a concept which has also been studied, but these are, usually, not lattices. Actually, one could have both operations be the same...

@amrsa I think a expansion/reduct looks close but the wiki page seems to suggest that the structures need the same number of functions. Is that the case or would you be able to apply it here?

@NeRoboto What wiki page? Reduct is a very standard concept in Universal Algebra (and perhaps Model Theory, but here I'm not sure) and it is as in the first comment. Expansion is, I think, also more or less standard, in the meaning given above; could you be confusing with extension?

@amrsa This one
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduct
But I think I may have misread it. I suppose it can have a different number of operators the way it is written on the page.

@NeRoboto There you go, in that page there is the concept of reduct, the same definitions I gave, although with a different notation, and the one of expansion, as the opposite process, as in my first comment.
